# How to set a list of new columns values to 0.0 in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a list of columns

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

and a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

I want to add these `cols` to `df` and set them to `0.0`.

```
for col in cols:
  df[col] = 0.0
```

works, but

```
df[cols] = 0.0
```

results in the error

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Why does this not work? When you want to query column values for a list of columns, you can pass in the list of columns in a similar way, but it seems initialization doesn't work in the same manner.

Comment: @s_pike Yes, I think that does

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your application but a column must have some rows i.e a list.
From your question,I recommend creating a dictionary with your columns and a list  containing lists of 0.0 .See the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
#source https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html
# depending on how may values you want in your column change the variable 
number_of_rows_in_column=10
# create a dictionary add a list of 0.0s under as value for each column
data=dict(zip(cols,[[ 0.0 for _ in range(number_of_rows_in_column) ] for _ in range(len(cols))]))
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for some information